# Driving a raw Dot-Matrix LC Display

Tags: lcd

So, I have this raw 32x32px monochrome reflective dot-matrix LC panel which I got from a toy. It looks like this:

[image]

I would like to drive it in my own circuit. I know how to drive LED matrices using shift registers etc. However the display in question has not 64, but 84 pins. The part number on the back is `JS171012`, but for that I have found zero results on the internet.

Is it possible to find out what those extra 10 pins do (I assume some of them are GND and VCC?) and use this display in my circuit? I'm using an ESP32 as my microcontroller, and I have a CPU core free so I can do the constant updating on there.

Comment: Are you aware that an LCD needs to be driven with AC, not DC?

Comment: @Hearth No I was not, that's why I am asking :-) Why does it need AC, and how would I produce that from a DC source?

Comment: with a square wave generator, as usually found in an LCD driver IC or micrococontroller peripheral. You can't directly hook this up to your microcontroller if it doesn't have one of these.

Comment: @MarcusMüller okay... so if I don't want to spend a significant amount of time trying to build a driver with many different parts, I should go looking for a new display?

Comment: @Twometer It needs AC because if you drive it with DC it will eventually be destroyed. I'm not sure the exact mechanism of it, but I know that applying DC across an LCD segment will, after a little while (I'm not sure exactly how long, but I think it's at least a few hours, not necessarily continuous), cause the segment to stop working. If you alternate the polarity of the voltage by applying a square wave of a reasonable frequency, this failure mechanism isn't a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Driving a LCD display is a lot like driving a matrix LED display with some differences.

Like an matrix LED display or a multi digit seven-segment display, the LCD elements will be organized into groups which share a common pin. These groups are often referred to as "backplanes". So your first task will be to identify those groups and the common pins.

Then you can refer to this Microchip app note:

*AVR241: Direct driving of LCD display using general IO*

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/doc2569.pdf

Basically you generate the AC wave form by connecting two GPIO pins to the two ends of the LCD element and toggle them either in phase or out of phase with respect to each other. In phase means the GPIO pins have the same output, out of phase means they have the opposite output level -- i.e. when one GPIO pin is HIGH the other is LOW and vice-versa. If the GPIO pins are in phase the segment will not be energized and if out of phase the segment will be energized.

You need to keep toggling the GPIO pins, and that can consume a lot of microcontroller's time if it doesn't have dedicated hardware to help it. That's why LCD driver chips (e.g. like an NXP PCF85162 or similar driver) is usually used.

Driving a large number of LCD elements also require a lot of I/O pins which is another reason why the task is off-loaded to special driver chips. But driving a small number of segments is feasible with the average MCU.

Comment: Oh I see, so it is technically possible. The AVR document looks very helpful! I don't have 84 pins on my MCU though, can this switching be done using (lots of) shift registers? Also, how would I go about finding the backplane and common pins on my LCD?

Comment: Sure it can be done with shift registers -- it'll just take longer for the MCU to set and clear bits.